# need to frame a query using like passing output of a select query in like string

Tags: sql

can anyone help me in framing aquery using like :
need to fetch from a table passing acct_nbrof another select query in like tag

Query I'm expecting is like :

```
select * from unbld_usage_sum where event_data like '%**(select sbscrp_id from sbscrp_asgm where acct_nbr='0032581922')**%';
```

Answer (score 0):

join both tables,

```
select  a.*, b.*
from    unbld_usage_sum a
        INNER JOIN sbscrp_asgm b
            ON a.event_data = b.sbscrp_id
where   b.acct_nbr='0032581922'
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from unbld_usage_sum where event_data like '%'+(select sbscrp_id from sbscrp_asgm where acct_nbr='0032581922')+'%';

Answer (score 0):

How about the query:

```
select *
from  
  unbld_usage_sum T1 INNER JOIN sbscrp_asgm T2
      ON T1.event_data = '%' + T2.sbscrp_id + '%'
where   
   T2.acct_nbr='0032581922'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
declare @searchkey nvarchar(200)
set @searchkey = (select sbscrp_id from sbscrp_asgm where acct_nbr='0032581922')
select * from unbld_usage_sum where event_data like '%' + @searchkey + '%'
```